# Setting up SystemC-AMS with Eclipse and Cygwin - Undefined Reference Error

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, systemc

I installed *SystemC (2.3.2)* and *SystemC-AMS (2.1)* under Windows 7 in Cygwin without issues as follows:

```
./configure --with-systemc=/home/user/Workspace/systemc-2.3.2
make
make install
```

I then went into Eclipse (Photon - 4.8.0) and created a new C/C++ Project. For the Toolchain I chose `Cygwin GCC`. Furthermore, I applied the following settings to the project:

Include Paths:

```
"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-2.3.2\include"    
"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-ams-2.1\include"
```

Library Search Paths:

```
"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-2.3.2\lib-cygwin64"
"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-ams-2.1\lib-cygwin64"
```

Library:

```
systemc
systemc-ams
```

Now I try to execute the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "systemc.h"
#include "systemc-ams.h"

int sc_main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    sca_tdf::sca_signal <double> out1;
    return 0;
}
```

I get an Undefined Reference error:

```
11:36:35 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project SystemC-AMS-Test ****
make all 
Building file: ../TestSCAMS.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -I"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-2.3.2\include" -I"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-ams-2.1\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"TestSCAMS.d" -MT"TestSCAMS.o" -o "TestSCAMS.o" "../TestSCAMS.cpp"
Finished building: ../TestSCAMS.cpp

Building target: SystemC-AMS-Test.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++ -L"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-2.3.2\lib-cygwin64" -L"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-ams-2.1\lib-cygwin64" -o "SystemC-AMS-Test.exe"  ./TestSCAMS.o   -lsystemc -lsystemc-ams
C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-ams-2.1\lib-cygwin64/libsystemc-ams.a(convert_from_string.o):convert_from_string.cpp:(.text$_ZN8sca_util18sca_implementation18convert_by_istreamIN5sc_dt8sc_logicEEEbRT_RKSs[_ZN8sca_util18sca_implementation18convert_by_istreamIN5sc_dt8sc_logicEEEbRT_RKSs]+0x18f): undefined reference to `sc_dt::sc_logic::scan(std::istream&)'
C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-ams-2.1\lib-cygwin64/libsystemc-ams.a(convert_from_string.o):convert_from_string.cpp:(.text$_ZN8sca_util18sca_implementation18convert_by_istreamIN5sc_dt8sc_logicEEEbRT_RKSs[_ZN8sca_util18sca_implementation18convert_by_istreamIN5sc_dt8sc_logicEEEbRT_RKSs]+0x18f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `sc_dt::sc_logic::scan(std::istream&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:46: SystemC-AMS-Test.exe] Error 1

11:36:38 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.199ms)
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Where `make install` put the header and shared libs ?

Comment: C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-2.3.2\lib-cygwin64

C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-ams-2.1\lib-cygwin64

In those paths there are libsystemc.a and libsystemc-ams.a

Comment: Change paths from windows style `"C:\cygwin64\home\user\Workspace\systemc-2.3.2\include" ` to posix  `"/home/user/Workspace/systemc-2.3.2/include"`

Comment: Same issue as before, so compilation works, but linking throws the error as shown above.

Comment: try inverting the order of "-lsystemc -lsystemc-ams" to " -lsystemc-ams -lsystemc"

Comment: wow, that actually did the trick, thanks a lot. If you create an answer I will thumbs up and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms like windows, cygwin and others undefined symbols are not allowed at link stage.
The link order matters

`"-lsystemc -lsystemc-ams"` is not the same of `" -lsystemc-ams -lsystemc"`

as `systemc-ams` is using symbols of `systemc` the second version guarantees that all symbols are resolved at link stage.
It is also the reason why compiling any program the libraries invocation are at the end of the command.

`gcc dummy.c -lsystemc` works while  `gcc -lsystemc dummy.c` fails with `undefined symbols` error